# In Jupyter, how can I use the matplotlib ggplot style by default?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

In a jupyter notebook, I can run

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

And that allows me to use the ggplot style for plots. How can I make this default, say, by putting it in a config file somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**One way** would be to use IPython's startup files to run arbitrary script for all IPython sessions.
For this to work you would need to place any `file.py` into `<user-home-dir>/.ipython/profile_default/startup` folder.
This file can then have this code, which will be executed when IPython starts:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

---

**Another approach** is to modify the `matplotlibrc` with settings of `ggplot` which you can get with:

```
plt.style.library['ggplot']
```

Which will output:

```
RcParams({u'axes.axisbelow': True,
          u'axes.edgecolor': u'white',
          u'axes.facecolor': u'#E5E5E5',
          u'axes.grid': True,
          u'axes.labelcolor': u'#555555',
          u'axes.labelsize': u'large',
          u'axes.linewidth': 1.0,
          u'axes.prop_cycle': cycler(u'color', [u'#E24A33', u'#348ABD', u'#988ED5', u'#777777', u'#FBC15E', u'#8EBA42', u'#FFB5B8']),
          u'axes.titlesize': u'x-large',
          u'figure.edgecolor': u'0.50',
          u'figure.facecolor': u'white',
          u'font.size': 10.0,
          u'grid.color': u'white',
          u'grid.linestyle': u'-',
          u'patch.antialiased': True,
          u'patch.edgecolor': u'#EEEEEE',
          u'patch.facecolor': u'#348ABD',
          u'patch.linewidth': 0.5,
          u'xtick.color': u'#555555',
          u'xtick.direction': u'out',
          u'ytick.color': u'#555555',
          u'ytick.direction': u'out'})
```

Pasting those lines (`key : value` part) in `matplotlibrc` at the end will make `ggplot` style effective by default.